# Nuxt auth redirect when not logged in not working

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt and the Auth module. I'm trying to redirect users to a login page when they aren't logged in.

nuxt.config.js:

```
auth: {
  redirect: {
    login: '/account/inloggen',
    logout: '/account/uitloggen',
    callback: '/account/aanmelden',
    home: '/'
  },
  strategies: {
    google: {
      access_token_endpoint: '****/social?identityProvider=Google',
      access_type: 'offline',
      client_id: '*****.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/account/aanmelden',
      response_type: 'code',
      token_key: 'jwt',
      userinfo_endpoint: '****/user/profile'
    }
  },
  cookie: {
    options: {
      maxAge: 86400
    }
  }
  // localStorage: false
},
```

I'm reading the [docs](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options/)

> login: User will be redirected to this path if login is required.

But I can't find where/how I require a user to log in.

The `home: '/'` redirect does work, when the user logs in they get redirected to the root of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer on [Github](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/134#issuecomment-462368310)

> I've ran into this issue as well. My mistake was having auth: false set on my login page. If you have it, just remove it.

```
<script>
export default {
  auth: false
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the [`auth` middleware](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware) either globally

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
router: {
  middleware: ['auth']
}
```

or per route

`Something.vue`

```html
<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'auth'
}
</script>
```